# How can I format a String number to have commas in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, format, distance

i have this code to calculate distance from 2 points(lat,lon)

```
val distance = distanceInKm(3.140853,21.422510,101.693207,39.826168)
val number3digits:Double = String.format("%-10.4f%n%n", distance).toDouble()
distancetomakkah.text = "$number3digits"
```

but i'm getting this output:

10891.3684

and i want the output to be like this:

10,891

i tried to change the format to:
("%-10.4f%n%n"),("%,d") and many others but i keep getting this error

```
f != java.lang.string
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

```
String.format("%-10.4f%n%n", distance).toDouble()
```

Your format is not being applied. After formatting your returned value of `distanceInKm` as a `String`, you are calling [`toDouble`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double.html), undoing any formatting you did.

```
distancetomakkah.text = "$number3digits"
```

`number3digits` is a `Double`, and default formatting is applied when you use string interpolation to assign `.text`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
String.format("%-,10.4f%n%n", distance);
```

The result is of type `String`
That wouldn't be portable of course, since the `,` is not used in some `Locale`s

Comment: The `,` only tells the formatter to use groupings. What symbol it actually uses to separate groupings depends on the locale. The method you used in your example relies on the default locale, but there's an overload that allows you to specify a locale. For example, if you did `String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%,-10.4f%n%n", distance)` it would use `.` for groupings and `,` for the decimal point.

Comment: *The , only tells the formatter to use groupings.* Thanks for that. I thought it meant to use that character literally